# Facebook Games and Flash Issue

Tags: flash

My wife recently switched to xubuntu and she has run into an issue. I have googled but had no luck with a solution. She is trying to play a facebook game and getting the error that flash 19 or greater is required. I have installed flashplayer-installer and https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/ shows version 30.0.0.154 installed. 30 > 19 so she should be good but no. Also when I look at firefox's plugins list it shows Shockwave flash 13.1 r2. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on an 18.04 machine?

Comment: Try to reinstall `flashplugin-installer`. Or install `adobe-flashplugin` instead. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is running on Ubuntu 18.04, you can follow this method:

- Open Terminal (**alt+ctl+T**)
- Type of copy and past `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` then press **Enter**
- Blindly type **root user password** and then **Enter**
- `Y` followed by **Enter**
- Wait until the installation is complete

**Don't forget to restart your Browser**

Hope it helps!